Cannot retrieve the N;N relationship from plugin using akeXrmEasy framework
I am trying to set unit tests for an N:N relationship in an Associate/Disassociate plugin but it fails in the "context.GetRelationship().SchemaName" statement. From what I can tell, that function is part of the FakeXrmEasy "context" but the plugin function is from its executeContext. So, how do I replicate the plugin call with that from FakeXrmEasy? Then again, the FakeXrmEasy function requires an argument when the plugin's executionContext does not. What am I missing?
 **Here is the FakeXrmEasy code.**
   // Create the Team - INL Web Roles association
       context.AddRelationship("inl_INLWebRole_Team_Association", new XrmFakedRelationship  
 
 {
     IntersectEntity = inl_INLWebRole_Team.EntityLogicalName,
     Entity1LogicalName = Team.EntityLogicalName,
     Entity1Attribute = "teamid",
     Entity2LogicalName = inl_INLWebRole.EntityLogicalName,
     Entity2Attribute = "inl_inlwebroleid"
    });

 **and a call to the plugin**   
    var executionContext = new XrmFakedPluginExecutionContext()
         {
             MessageName = message.ToString(),
             Stage = (int)StageEnum.PostOperation,
             UserId = Guid.NewGuid(),    // dummy user
             PrimaryEntityName = (targetEntity != null ? targetEntity.LogicalName : "none"),
             PrimaryEntityId = (targetEntity != null ? targetEntity.Id : Guid.Empty),
             PreEntityImages = (imageType == ImageTypeEnum.PreImage ? images : null),
             PostEntityImages = (imageType == ImageTypeEnum.PostImage ? images : null),
             InputParameters = inputParameters,
         };

     // Execute the plugin
     context.ExecutePluginWith<TeamMembershipPlugin>(executionContext);

**And here is a code snippet of the plugin.**

   protected override void ExecutePlugin(IExtendedPlugin executeContext)
    {  
 
 InitializeContext(executeContext);        
       tracer.Trace("Beginning execution of Team Membership Plugin");       

       // Get the action to process       
       var processAction = ActionCall.None;       
      if (this.context.MessageName == MessageNameEnum.Associate.ToString())       
      {   
        processAction = ActionCall.AddRole;  
      }   
      else if (this.context.MessageName == MessageNameEnum.Disassociate.ToString())   
     {    
         processAction = ActionCall.RemoveRole;  
     }    
     else  
    {     
       return;  
    }  
    // Process either the team membership (team or queue)     
    // or the web Role association. Otherwise quit.       
    var relationshipName = executionContext.GetRelationship().SchemaName;

The process fails on that last line because there is no relationship in that context.
